# KeyValueDataContractDeserializer with multi value on form post

Tags: servicestack

I have a Razor page which does a standard HTTP post and thus ends up going through the `KeyValueDataContractDeserializer` for deserialization.

This is designed to only accept the first instance of a multi field post, for example when more than one instance of a checkbox is posted.

This can bee seen in the code (from [DictionaryExtensions.cs](https://github.com/justinrolston/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceModel/DictionaryExtensions.cs)) below:

```
if (values != null && values.Length > 0)
{
    map[key] = values[0];
}
```

Is there a way that I can post the same field name twice and have the `KeyValueDataContractDeserializer` treat it as a multi-value field?

Is it a bug or a design choice that only the first value from a `NameValueCollection` is recognised?